# Why $\cot^{-1}x$ is an odd function in Mathematica

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, even-and-odd-functions

The function $f(x)=\cot^{-1} x$ is well known to be neither even nor odd because $\cot^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\cot^{-1} x$. it's domain is $(-\infty, \infty)$ and range is $(0, \pi)$. Today, I was surprised to notice that Mathematica treats it as an odd function, and yields its plot as given below:

[image]

How to reconcile this ? I welcome your comments.

Edit: I used: Plot[ArcCot[x], {x, -3, 3}] there to plot

Comment: Can you post the string you passed to Mathematica used to obtain this figure?

Comment: I used: Plot[ArcCot[x],{x,-3,3}], there. I have also put it in my edit now.

Comment: It depends on how you define $\cot^{-1}$ – as the inverse of $\cot$ on the interval $(0, \pi)$ or on the interval $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$.

Comment: I am afraid it should not be left to choice. Similarly $\cos^{-1}(x)$ is also of mixed parity as $\cos^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\cos^{-1} x$. it is not an even function.

Comment: The difference is explained here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html.

Answer (score 2):

From [Inverse Cotangent](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InverseCotangent.html) on Wolfram MathWorld:

> There are at least two possible conventions for defining the inverse
> cotangent. This work follows the convention of Abramowitz and Stegun
> (1972, p. 79) and the Wolfram Language, taking $\cot^{-1}x$ to have
> range $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, a discontinuity at $x=0$, and the branch cut
> placed along the line segment $(-i,i)$.
>
> This definition is also consistent, as it must be, with the Wolfram
> Language's definition of `ArcTan`, so `ArcCot[z]` is equal to
> `ArcTan[1/z]`.
>
> A different but common convention (e.g., Zwillinger 1995, p. 466;
> Bronshtein and Semendyayev, 1997, p. 70; Jeffrey 2000, p. 125) defines
> the range of  $\cot^{-1}x$ as $(0,\pi)$, thus giving a function that
> is continuous on the real line $\Bbb R$.

The former definition is what Mathematica uses. Note that with that definition, $\cot^{-1}(0) = \pi/2$, so it is an odd function only if you exclude $x=0$ from the domain.

The latter definition satisfies $\cot^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\cot^{-1} x$ and is not an odd function.

Comment: Mathematica.SE provides [some tricks, with some drawbacks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39434/redefine-arccot-to-be-inverse-of-range-0-pi)

Answer (score 0):

We have that $\cot^{-1}(-x)$ is invertible only on suitable restrictions, in this case it seems Mathematica is considering the following definition

$$f(x)=\cot^{-1}(x): \mathbb R \to \left(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2\right)$$

that is also the definition used by [Wolfram](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcCot.html).

Comment: Mathematica *is* Wolfram.

Comment: @YvesDaoust All is clear then! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the Range of $f(x)=\cot^{-1} x$ as $(0,\pi)$ and hence the mixed parity of this function gets  preference as then $f(x)$ is continuous in the its domain $(-\infty, \infty)$, specially at $x=0$. Then $\cot^{-1}(-x)=\pi-\cot (x)$.

In problem solving, for students, teachers and examiners this convention is most welcome for the sake of consistency. According to this $\cot^{-1} x$ function should look as below:

[image]